# is there any way to skip a make's target?

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to add a patch so that a software can compile and run correctly, unfortunately in order to add the change I am trying I always run into an annoying code style check error. Is there any way to skip this step?

Comment: Maybe, but not generically. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you post the makefile(s) (or at least the relevant parts).

Answer (score 9):

If the makefile looks like this:

```
code-style-check: source.c
        tool-you-dont-have

myprogram: code-style-check source.c
        compile source.c -o myprogram
```

then you can avoid running `tool-you-dont-have` by creating a file called `code-style-check`:

```
touch code-style-check
```

Make will see that `code-style-check` is newer than `source.c` and won't try to rebuild it.

This doesn't work if `code-style-check` is a phony target declared with `.PHONY: code-style-check`: phony targets aren't file names.

Note that if `code-style-check` has dependencies, they won't count anymore for the sake of deciding whether to rebuild `myprogram`. It doesn't matter in the example above because `code-style-check` doesn't have any dependencies that `myprogram` doesn't have.

An alternative solution with GNU make that works even for a phony target is to run

```
make -o code-style-check …
```

The option `-o` tells make to consider `code-style-check` to be older than anything that's already there (unlike the `touch` approach which makes the file newer than anything that's already there), and also not to try to rebuild it. Once again, if dependencies of `code-style-check` were also needed for `myprogram`, they won't be built.